# Discord bot timed mute channel on event

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm new using python I'm not that good at all and I wanted to create a bot meme based when a user says "Za warudo!" the channel will get muted for 10 seconds and send an image of a gif also set
so I could do the image it was pretty easy to do I also want to add a cooldown of around 120 seconds or more I don't want this command to get spammed.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  channel = message.channel
  if message.content.startswith('ZA WARUDO!'):
    with open('zawarudo.gif', 'rb') as picture:
      await client.send_file(channel, picture)
```

anyway, I just can't understand how to do this timed channel mute should I use a role for it? if I do how am I gonna give it to everyone in the server?

Comment: with a little bit of play i think its something around the discord.permissions() and .update method but i don't think i still understand it

Comment: so after a lot of time i finally did something but i couldn't do it with a everyone role here what i did to do it but no cool down just to set permission  "await channel.set_permissions(message.author, send_messages=False)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to do it myself

```
      await channel.set_permissions(everyone, send_messages=False)
      await asyncio.sleep(10)
      await channel.set_permissions(everyone, send_messages=True)
```